# How to bind an event to all input fields in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to bind all input fields on a 'form page' to the blur event in jquery.  If I put a breakpoint in the each it gets paused so I think the code is being called on page load properly and the loop is working okay.  I think the syntax is correct for binding the event as well ?  I am not getting the alert when I do anything (leave!) any of the fields in my form though so I think something about this is wrong ?  Can anyone point it out to me ?

```
//for each item in the form (:input "selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.") 
    $(' :input').each(function () {
        $('this').bind('blur', function(){
            alert ("nasty, shoudl be a log!");
            myfunction();
        })
    })
```

Comment: `$(':input').on('blur', function() { // DO THINGS });`

Comment: just another comment: using it the way i proposed, will eliminate the need for `.each`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
    $(this).bind('blur', function(){
```

without the quotes.

Comment: Besides, now it is more common to use `$(this).on('blur', function() { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks I'd switched from on to bind when it didn't work.  Missed the real point sadly!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":input").bind('blur',() => yourfunction());
```

Just add the event call into your jQuery selector.